# What to do if there are multiple duplicate questions, all having good answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently came across these questions:

- [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php)
- [How do I find a user's IP address with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768/how-do-i-find-a-users-ip-address-with-php)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437771/how-can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-a-php-webservice

All of them are asking the exact same thing. The first question is the first hit for "*user ip php*" (and many other) search term on Google. The top answer has 274 votes and the question's been viewed over 240903 times. Note that it also has **6 delete votes**.

The second and third questions also address the same query. Some of the answers on these thread has useful information. I feel this could be a lot more organized and clean if these posts were merged together. Not only it'd help keep the site clean, it will also make close-voting easier. We'll have all the information on a single-question.

I thought about flagging the second and third for moderator attention and then requesting for a merge, but I wanted to clarify before doing that. What do you think is the best approach in this case?

Comment: I'm wary about merges - especially with old Q&A I fear there would be too many answers. As long as they are properly dupe-closed with each other,  the most important part of the job is done.

Comment: @Pëkka: Sure, that's how it's been all these years. But then the valuable information is split up on different posts. If they're all in one place, folks would benefit from it, don't you think? And as for low quality answers, just delete them (assuming that's a possibility)?

Comment: @AmalMurali Depending on the situation, when I find questions like this, I sometimes vote to close them all as duplicates of the question with the highest voted answer. The rationale is, the information isn't actually lost, because it appears in the "Linked Questions" list on the right (don't forget about this), and so users unsatisfied with the answer can easily browse the other questions. Even if all the answers aren't in the same place, at least they're easily accessible. Also the duplicates link directly to the "hub" question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Clean-Up Process:**

- Reopen [3003145](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php).
- Close [55768](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768/how-do-i-find-a-users-ip-address-with-php) as duplicate of [3003145](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php) and merge.
- Delete repeat and other crappy answers.
- Clean up comments on question and remaining answers.
- Close [1437771](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437771/how-can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-a-php-webservice) as duplicate of [3003145](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php) and delete (too much copy-pasting of content on that one, not worth keeping around).
- Protect [3003145](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php) from future repeat and other crappy answers.

Clean-up process completed.

**Note:** These events did not particularly happen in this order, but they all happened.

Answer (score 6):

You pick the one with the best answers, and close the others as duplicates of that one.

Yes, note that I said **best answer** and not necessarily **oldest question**.

Now, if there's truly a mess and there's too many "canonical" questions with good answers that are all worth keeping (preventing one from deleting the excess questions), it's worth getting a moderator involved in order to merge all the answers back to a single canonical.

**There's no need to delete duplicates** - Unless there's a *lot* of them (tens or hundreds), duplicates act as flagposts for similar wording and duplicate problems. Deleting them is often counter-productive.